# OMNET++ INTERFACE WITH PYTHON

Tags: python, omnet++

I want to modify AODV protocol. The idea is I want AODV to take different routing decisions.
I have designed my own protocol based on AODV in python. It uses game-theory to find the best rout in terms of security and energy consumption and shortest path.
MY QUESTION is that: can I build an agent in python to take routing decision and then continues in OMNET++ with the routing.
Can we see if the INET framework can be interfaced with Python ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this wrapper class will help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14192/Embedding-Python-In-Your-C-Application